# splice not overriding element in an array at the specified index inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to transform an array into a slightly different format, and am using the splice for now like below:

```
letnewArray.splice( idx , 0 , obj );
```

My entire code can be seen below:

```js
let yaml_doc_json = [{
      name: 'guidIds',
      ids: ['209A3935-2305-4786-960B-BB008F3E9DC9',
        'C10D76D2-89A3-4F28-B64E-2D78C953B283',
        'B7164432-94B3-4096-A9EA-181D0F00D25E',
        'DA366048-557F-42ED-AB1D-3B2196278E86'
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'keyMessage',
      ids: ['Enbril_RA_30.00',
        'Enbril_RA_40.00',
        'Enbril_RA_50.00',
        'Enbril_RA_10.00'
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'SequenceName',
      ids: ['1_KEY_LUN_09_2017_Ukr_main',
        '1_KEY_LUN_09_2017_Ukr_sl01',
        '1_KEY_LUN_09_2017_Ukr_sl02',
        '1_KEY_LUN_09_2017_Ukr_sl03'
      ]
    }
  ],
  letnewArray = [];


yaml_doc_json.forEach((e, i) => {
  //console.log(e);
  let id_name = yaml_doc_json[i].name;
  //console.log(id_name);
  e['ids'].forEach((elem, idx) => {
    console.log(idx);
    let obj = {
      id_name: elem
    }
    letnewArray.splice(idx, 0, obj);
  });
});

console.log(letnewArray);
```

How come i get 12 elements in `letnewArray` even though `idx` is always between 0-3 ? should't the elements at the specific index be overridden everytime the forEach loop runs ? why is the overriding now happening ? what am i really doing wrong here ?

Comment: Inspect `letnewArray` after the `forEach()` is done and everything should make more sense to you.

Comment: The second argument of `splice()` is the `deleteCount`. If it is zero then all you do is insert the new item and all others  at that index and beyond will shift to the right

Comment: So what are your expected results?

Comment: @charlietfl my expected result would be an array of with a length of 4.

Comment: So only the last group of ids in initial array? Is that all you really need? No need to loop over the others if that is the case

Comment: @charlietfl yes that all i need for now to work and i need to do it this way :) this is just a minimalist example , i did't want to post my final requirement as it would be too much code :)

Comment: Seems like all you need then is a simple `map()` of the ids in last object of main array  `letarray = yaml_doc_json[yaml_doc_json.length-1].ids.map(id=>({id_name:id}))`

Comment: @charlietfl thanks alot buddy for the help :) much appreciated. this solved my problem , if you can add it as an answer with a MDN link or something , i'll accept `The second argument of splice() is the deleteCount. If it is zero then all you do is insert the new item and all others at that index and beyond will shift to the right ` .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@charlietfl answered this in the comments !.

> The second argument of splice() is the deleteCount. If it is zero then
>   all you do is insert the new item and all others at that index and
>   beyond will shift to the right.

Comment: Then, Its not your answer is it?

Comment: @Dementic , It is not my answer , but it is the answer that resolved my query !

Answer (score 1):

The 12 elements in the `letnewArray` come from having each of the three elements in `yaml_doc_json` elaborated four times (the number of `ids` elements).

The fact that there are 12 is because of the syntax of `Array.prototype.splice`. The complete reference can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

The important part is the syntax:

`array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])`

Let us turn back to your code. We have

`letnewArray.splice( idx , 0 , obj );`

 Going by the definition above, we can infer

- `array => letnewArray`
- `start => idx`
- `deleteCount => 0`
- `item1 => obj`

The various `item1, item2, ...` elements are added to the array. Therefore, each time the for loop cycles through, we delete 0 items and add 1 element.

This shows why the ending elements in the `letnewArray` variable are 12.

I hope to have been useful.

Answer (score -1):

Splice will add the third argument to existing array. Refer https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_splice1

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I guess he is not aware of how splice works in the first place.

Comment: Certainly aware that the third argument gets inserted or wouldn't have anything in the array. The question is about the indexing

Comment: From his question he thinks it will override the element instead of appending.